# tar appending extract issues

Tags: command-line, tar

I append file_1 with `tar -rf folder.tar file_1` and when I list the files with `tar -tf folder.tar` it shows file_1 inside the archive.

However when extract via terminal with `tar -xvf folder.tar` in same or any other directory, file_1 is missing out. If I the archive extract via GUI file_1 is extracted.

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 using GNU tar 1.29.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What version of tar and Ubuntu?

Comment: 17.10 ubuntu budgie.

tar (GNU tar) 1.29
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.

Comment: Can't reproduce either, using tar 1.28 on 16.04. Is it possible that `file_1` has a leading dot and is therefore just hidden for `ls` when used without the `-a` option? If that's not it please show us exactly how you proceeded and where you were expecting a different output. Please remember to *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments.

Comment: Well, now, after some time I try lot's of things I try to reboot pc and it extracts it with no problems via terminal.

However, I try to create some random  .tar files or tar.gz and append random files in it. If I don't reboot. The same issue is happening.

Far as I know I try everything that includes appending and extracting options via terminal. Issues are fixed only when I reboot pc. I try only restart X and that didn't help to.